# Jquery or Underscore how to find the current object is existing with old array of objects?

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I am getting input from user, the constrain is they should not give the same information for multiple time.

I store the datas in array. when user click the submit, I need to test whether the data is new or it's exist.

I am happy to implement both jquery or underscore, I try is not works:

```
datas1 = [
        {"name": "Test Task #1", "date": "12/01/2012", "assigned": "John Doe" },
        {"name": "Test Task #2", "date": "12/02/2012", "assigned": "John Doe" },
        {"name": "Test Task #3", "date": "12/03/2012", "assigned": "John Doe" },
        {"name": "Test Task #4", "date": "12/04/2012", "assigned": "John Doe" },
        {"name": "Test Task #5", "date": "12/05/2012", "assigned": "John Doe" },
        {"name": "Test Task #6", "date": "12/06/2012", "assigned": "John Doe" },
        {"name": "Test Task #7", "date": "12/07/2012", "assigned": "John Doe" }
    ]

var newVal = {"name": "Test Task #8", "date": "12/07/2012", "assigned": "John Doe" };

var changedObj = _.find(newVal, function(obj, index) {
    return obj != datas1[index];
});

console.log(changedObj); // getting newVal - looking for true or false.
```

any one help me?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28T9K/)

Comment: @Satpal I am not get any result. always getting empty array.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/28T9K/3/ hope it works for you or http://jsfiddle.net/28T9K/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UnderscoreJS it's not so difficult to find an object that exists in an array. Indeed you have to use the [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) function, but in the find function you should use the [isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) function to check if both objects are the same.

```
var result = _.find(list, function(val){ 
    return _.isEqual(object, val)
});
```

This gives you back an object. So you can check if result is an object.

```
_.isObject(result) ? true : false;
```

Finally you can abstract this functionality so you will end up with something like this:

```
function objectExists(object, list) {
     var result = _.find(list, function(val){ 
        return _.isEqual(object, val)
    });
    return _.isObject(result) ? true : false;
}
```

#### Usage:

```
if(objectExists(newVal, datas1)) {
   console.log('object does exist');
} else {
   console.log('object does not exist');
}
```